# Ubuntu 16.04 + libssl0.9.8 - has no installation candidate?

Tags: apt, 16.04, software-installation, ssl

I'm on Xubuntu/ Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to install libssl0.9.8:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Any specific reason to install just that package?

Comment: @Braiam i tried to install it for shiny server. the error from installing the server lead me to this. but now i have solved the problem with shiny server.

Comment: @teelou Can I ask: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There has been a *version bump* for Xenial Xerus:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

is what you need...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Packages: libssl1.0.0 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1 and others) [security]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libssl1.0.0)

Comment: v. 1.0.0 is not compatible with 0.9.8.

Answer (score 7):

That error occurs when a package is not available from the repositories. In other words, that package does not exist for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial). See it [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl0.9.8). It stops at Trusty (14.04)

If you really need to install it, download the package manually and install. This is how:

- Download the package for your particular architecture (32/64bits) from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libssl0.9.8).
- Extract the file(s).
- Open a terminal, go to the extracted folder and run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i file.deb
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```

(The latter command will install any dependency libraries needed, as listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libssl0.9.8))

**NOTE**: Installing old packages and their dependencies can be risky, as it can conflict with current libraries. There might be a reason why the package **is not** available for your Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the trusty package manually:

i386: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libssl0.9.8/download

amd64: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download

other: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libssl0.9.8